# Как загрузить контент если перешли по определенному табу (tab)?

Tags: php, tab

Есть страница `https://site.com/zapis/` как загрузить определенный контент например: `echo 'Yes';` если перешли на #tab3 `https://site.com/zapis/#tab3` ??

Comment: `#` -  якорь обычно используются для перемещения по странице.

Comment: @And не всегда, на ява-скриптовских интерфейсах бывает очень полезен и для загрузки динамической, и в истории сохраняется так что можно жать и назад и вперед без перезагрузки страницы. Только вот что нужно топик стартеру я понял телепатически :)

Comment: @LeonidMew так делают только те, кто живет прошлым и те, кто не понимает, что делает в принципе.

Comment: @And Не согласен на счет прошлого, полезные плюшки можно получить используя эту строку. Главное понимать как это работает, и возможные последствия. Вот что делает топик стартер, вероятно не нужно и не полезно.

Comment: @LeonidMew, чушь полная. Прочитайте про `history API`

Comment: @And Посмотрите как gmail работает, первый попавшийся пример. Да и ваши слова что используется для перемещения по странице абсолютно верны, только перемещаться можно и в не видимые или даже не загруженные части страницы.

Comment: @LeonidMewб ага посмотрите как нетскейп работает. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ПХП скрипте нет доступа к тексту после #, но он доступен в javascript.
Если яваскрипт не подходит то делайте таб3 параметром, например:
`https://site.com/zapis/?tab=3`
`mod_rewrite` может переделать ссылку например в  `https://site.com/zapis/tab3`
Если не много вариантов таб то просто прописать в `.htaccess`

Может быть поможет такая идея: яваскриптом найти этот параметр, аяксом передать скрипту и результат скрипта ваше "Yes" как либо обработать.

Используется jQuery.

находим символы после #:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

условие напишите сами. если условие выполняется то следующий код обращается к серверу(без перезагрузки страницы, ajax):

Этот код загрузит то что вывел скрипт и присвоит значение блоку на странице:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'example.com',
  data: "addparamshere=something&tab3=1"
  error: function (data) {
    alert('Не удалось отправить заявку, попробуйте другой способ связи.');
  },
  success: function(data)
  {
    alert("Заявка успешно отправлена"); // show response from the php  script.
    $("#resultPlaceholder").html(data); // Присваиваем результат элементу с ид resultPlaceholder
  }
});
```

Comment: А у вас нету примера кода javascript? Никогда не дружила с javой (

Comment: java и javascript разные вещи. надо дружить, если пхп выучили то стоит двигается дальше и освоить яваскрипт. сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: А как правильно написать условия в javascript?? У меня ничего не получилось с кодом.

Comment: Я не знаю как там у вас табы переключаются. Условие типа такого: if(hash == 'tab3'). Надеюсь сможете найти место куда вставить, при переключении таба должно вызыватся. Либо событие повесить - при первом клике на таб вызвать функцию(в функцию вложить тот кусок что аякс запрос вызывает). Покажите минимальный пример кода и серверного и клиентского.

Comment: Я не понимаю делаю следующее условие: `var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
if(hash == 'tab3') {
   document.write('Да'); 
}
else {
   document.write('Нет'); 
}`  Выводится всегда `нет` почему??

Comment: А так если, что выводит? alert(window.location.hash.substring(1));  На клик по табу почему бы не повесить загрузку страницы. Если вы не понимаете то лучше бросить эти хеши. Делайте загрузку при клике по табу.

Comment: `alert(window.location.hash.substring(1));` - так выводит в сплывающем окне `tab3`

Comment: присвойте табам id, уникальный. Затем назначаем событие которое загрузит содержимое: $("#tabId3").onclick(function(){ /*сюда помещаем код с аяксом из ответа, настроив его на свои данные/параметры */ });

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85288/discussion-between-leonidmew-and--).

Comment: Спасибо все получилось! Только возникла новая проблема: в подключенном файле 3.html подключается файл .js В самом файле 3.html все отлично работает, а на странице с табом подключаемый .js не обрабатывается, html отлично выводится. :/

Comment: @ЮляФролова да, скрипты надо по особому - или загружать отдельно, паралельно с хтмл, или в шапке основной страницы. смотря что за скрипты. если это фрейворк используемый на нескольких страницах то грузите его в основной странице. Ну если получилось - можно отметить ответ как правильный :) Да, скрипт можно таким же кодом как хтмл скачать, отдельно, и вместо присваивания элементу хтмл - выполнить eval(data)

Comment: Проблема в том что скрипт сразу выполняется, и весь смысл чтобы он грузился с отдельной страницы. Можете войти в чат?

Answer (score -1):

> Данный код почему то не работает :/ на странице https://site.com/zapis/ все равно выводится Yes

Yes выводится из за того, что Вы ввели в строку для поиска необходимые символы

```
$url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '#tab3';
if (strpos($url,'#tab3') !== false) {
  echo 'Yes';
} else {
  echo 'NO';
}
```

Более работоспособным данный код будет выглядеть так:

```
$url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($url,'#tab3') === false) {
    echo 'NO';
} else {
    echo 'Yes';
}
```

Надеюсь, что мой ответ Вам помог.

Comment: К сожалению данный вариант не подходит, всегда выводится `echo 'NO';`

Comment: Сожалею, что не смог помочь. Дам совет по отладке: попытайтесь вывести значение переменой $url(echo $url;).Это может дать дополнительную информацию о проблеме.